# Indexes significantly slowing down queries while significantly speeding up others

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

## TLDR

I had some queries being slowed-down whenever I tried to `ORDER BY` any column other than the `PK`. I then added indices to the table, which sped up queries ordered by any numeric column, but significantly slowed down (around 20s before indices; >2min after indices being added) queries ordered by text columns. Adding indices for the text columns didn't help. Queries ordered by text columns were using one of the numeric column indices when I checked them with `EXPLAIN`. Need to know if there's any way to use indices to improve the speed of the queries when ordering by any column, numeric or textual, or at least the numeric columns, without having the side-effect of slowing down other important queries (such as the same ones but ordered by text columns).

## Context

I'm writing a backend that communicates with a MySQL database running locally, which stores some metadata about scientific papers. While writing tests for some queries through the backend, I notice some of the tests were taking very long to run. The database consists of the following tables:

```
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_padaone       |
+-------------------------+
| classification_2ndLay   |
| classifications_1stLay  |
| curationStatus_User     |
| geneIDsPerPMIDs_Counts  |
| geneIDs_PMIDs           |
| geneIDs_taxInfo_AccNumb |
| metadataPub             |
| padaone_query_cache     |
| taxID_taxName           |
| taxIDsPerPMIDs_Counts   |
| taxPath                 |
+-------------------------+
```

The table `padaone_query_cache` is the main table used for the queries and it's a collation of multiple columns present in other tables. Here's its schema (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE padaone_query_cache`, as suggested in the comments):

```
CREATE TABLE `padaone_query_cache` (
  `pmid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET
utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `abstract` varchar(10000) CHARACTER SET
utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `year_pub` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_author` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET
utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `citations` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `journal` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET
utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET
utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_layer_probability` decimal(8,
7) NOT NULL,
  `second_layer_probability` decimal(8,
7) NOT NULL,
  `taxon_names` mediumtext CHARACTER SET
utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pmid`),
  CONSTRAINT `padaone_query_cache_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pmid`) REFERENCES `metadataPub` (`PMID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;
```

This particular table is shaped pretty much the way I want to shape the results table on the frontend. Doing so makes queries much faster than using joins, the volume of data is not huge and storage space is not a major concern and the data will not change often, so it's OK to have this "intermediate" table. In the backend, some queries are performed two-step: first, I query a certain table, say `geneIDs_PMIDs` joined with `geneIDs_taxInfo_AccNumb`, to retrieve some ids (henceforth called `pmid`s in reference to how they're called in the table) and at the end I query the main table (`padaone_query_cache`) with whatever filters + an `IN` clause using this set of unique `pmid`s (or the intersection of multiple sets, if multiple secondary queries are performed) to retrieved the valid papers corresponding to a collection of user-defined filters. So far, all this works fine, but some queries were taking 20+ seconds to complete (which leads to bad UX).

### Some example queries without indices

This query (and similar ones) is pretty fast:

```sql
SELECT
    pmid
FROM
    padaone_query_cache
WHERE
    (((first_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.0)
        AND (second_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0))
        AND (title LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR title LIKE "%vaccine%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%vaccine%"))
ORDER BY
    pmid DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

It only selects and filters for fields present in the main table and it orders by the `PK` (the `pmid` column). This runs in less than a second. **BUT** one of the query parameters the user can and may change is the `ORDER BY` column. When that happens, things start slowing down heavily:

```sql
SELECT
    pmid
FROM
    padaone_query_cache
WHERE
    (((first_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.0)
        AND (second_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0))
        AND (title LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR title LIKE "%vaccine%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%vaccine%"))
ORDER BY
    year_pub DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

The above query only differs from the first one by the `ORDER BY` column, but yet it takes > 20s to complete. In this case I'm ordering by `year_pub` which is `INT(11) NULLABLE`. More so, there's the additional issue that `year_pub` (and other columns such as both `*_layer_probability` columns) are non-unique, which leads to inconsistent returned results, which will later be an issue when I'm doing pagination. To circumvent that, I add `pmid` as a tie-breaker in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT
    pmid
FROM
    padaone_query_cache
WHERE
    (((first_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.0)
        AND (second_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0))
        AND (title LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR title LIKE "%vaccine%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%vaccine%"))
ORDER BY
    year_pub DESC,
    pmid DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

This still takes roughly 20s to complete, so adding the extra column in the `ORDER BY` doesn't seem to be a particular issue.

Also, as an example of a composite query (using subqueries in MySQL, but in my backend I just make multiple queries, build a `Set` of valid unique `pmids` and build a final query that contains an `IN` clause passing in the `Set`):

```sql
SELECT
    pmid
FROM
    padaone_query_cache
WHERE
    (((first_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.0)
        AND (second_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0))
        AND (pmid IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT PMID AS pmid
        FROM
            geneIDs_PMIDs AS geneids_to_pmids
        INNER JOIN geneIDs_taxInfo_AccNumb AS geneids_to_taxids ON
            (geneids_to_pmids.geneIDs) = (geneids_to_taxids.geneIDs)
        WHERE
            EXISTS (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                taxPath
            WHERE
                taxPath.TaxID = geneids_to_taxids.TaxID
                AND FIND_IN_SET("7742", REPLACE(taxPath.LineagePath, "-", ",")) = 0))))
ORDER BY
    pmid DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Again, here the query is rather fast when I order by `pmid`. But our default ordering column is actually `first_layer_probability`, and ordering by any of the `*_layer_probability` columns indeed very important for us (and for the user, as it is the major feature of the application we're building). When I change the ordering to `ORDER BY first_layer_probability DESC, pmid DESC` tho, the query slows down to around 12s. When we choose to order by any of the string fields, the query slows down even more.

## My solution

First, I identified that the `ORDER BY` column was the major problem, but that's a feature that must be present anyways, so I couldn't do much about it. I then checked the table's indices, and noted that, besides the `PK`, no other indices existed. So I tried to create some to see if it helped, and it did - but it also made it far worse.

Indices using any of the numeric columns were actually pretty good. So something like:

```sql
CREATE INDEX first_layer_probability_index ON padaone_query_cache (first_layer_probability, pmid, second_layer_probability);
```

and:

```sql
CREATE INDEX second_layer_probability_index ON padaone_query_cache (second_layer_probability, pmid, first_layer_probability);
```

made the following query much faster (note that I'm doing `ORDER BY` either of the probability columns):

```sql
SELECT
    pmid
FROM
    padaone_query_cache
WHERE
    (((first_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.0)
        AND (second_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0))
        AND (title LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR title LIKE "%vaccine%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%vaccine%"))
ORDER BY
    [first_layer_probability|second_layer_probability] DESC,
    pmid DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

which yields the following `EXPLAIN` plans:

```sql
-- first_layer_probability
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys                                                | key                           | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | padaone_query_cache | range | first_layer_probability_index,second_layer_probability_index | first_layer_probability_index | 5       | NULL | 221297 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+

-- second_layer_probability
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys                                                | key                            | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | padaone_query_cache | range | first_layer_probability_index,second_layer_probability_index | second_layer_probability_index | 5       | NULL | 221297 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

It came down to below 1s, which was great. But it made the same query, just ordered by another column, such as text column like `title`, take > 2 minutes to complete. When asking MySQL to `EXPLAIN` the query, I see that the `first_layer_probability_index` is being used, but it slows the query down.

```sql
SELECT
    pmid
FROM
    padaone_query_cache
WHERE
    (((first_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.0)
        AND (second_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0))
        AND (title LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR title LIKE "%vaccine%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%vaccine%"))
ORDER BY
    title DESC,
    pmid DESC
LIMIT 20;

-- EXPLAIN
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys                                                | key                           | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                              |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | padaone_query_cache | range | first_layer_probability_index,second_layer_probability_index | first_layer_probability_index | 5       | NULL | 221297 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to create indices for the other columns, and it worked, but only for the numeric columns.

```sql
-- this query takes < 1s after the `year_pub_index` is added
SELECT
    pmid
FROM
    padaone_query_cache
WHERE
    (((first_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.0)
        AND (second_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0))
        AND (title LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR title LIKE "%vaccine%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%vaccine%"))
ORDER BY
    year_pub DESC,
    pmid DESC
LIMIT 20;

-- EXPLAIN plan
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys                                                | key            | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | padaone_query_cache | index | first_layer_probability_index,second_layer_probability_index | year_pub_index | 19      | NULL | 80   | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

For the text columns, it didn't work, the indices including them were never used and the queries were much slower than before creating any of the indices.

```sql
-- this is the same query that used `title` described above, but after the creation of the `title_index`
SELECT
    pmid
FROM
    padaone_query_cache
WHERE
    (((first_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.0)
        AND (second_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0))
        AND (title LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR title LIKE "%vaccine%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%mouse%"
            OR abstract LIKE "%vaccine%"))
ORDER BY
    title DESC,
    pmid DESC
LIMIT 20;

-- EXPLAIN
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys                                                | key                           | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                              |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | padaone_query_cache | range | first_layer_probability_index,second_layer_probability_index | first_layer_probability_index | 5       | NULL | 221297 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

On top of that, the composite queries (using the subqueries and `JOIN`s) also suffer from the same issue depending on the column used in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```sql
-- fast
SELECT
    pmid
FROM
    padaone_query_cache
WHERE
    (((first_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.0)
        AND (second_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0))
        AND (pmid IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT PMID AS pmid
        FROM
            geneIDs_PMIDs AS geneids_to_pmids
        INNER JOIN geneIDs_taxInfo_AccNumb AS geneids_to_taxids ON
            (geneids_to_pmids.geneIDs) = (geneids_to_taxids.geneIDs)
        WHERE
            EXISTS (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                taxPath
            WHERE
                taxPath.TaxID = geneids_to_taxids.TaxID
                AND FIND_IN_SET("7742", REPLACE(taxPath.LineagePath, "-", ",")) = 0))))
ORDER BY
    first_layer_probability DESC,
    pmid DESC
LIMIT 20;

-- EXPLAIN plan

+------+--------------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table               | type   | possible_keys                                                        | key                           | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra                    |
+------+--------------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | padaone_query_cache | range  | PRIMARY,first_layer_probability_index,second_layer_probability_index | first_layer_probability_index | 5       | NULL                              | 221297 | Using where; Using index |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | <subquery2>         | eq_ref | distinct_key                                                         | distinct_key                  | 4       | func                              | 1      |                          |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED       | geneids_to_taxids   | index  | PRIMARY                                                              | taxIDsAccNumb_ibfk_1          | 5       | NULL                              | 338377 | Using where; Using index |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED       | geneids_to_pmids    | ref    | PRIMARY,geneIDs_PMIDs_ibfk_2                                         | geneIDs_PMIDs_ibfk_2          | 4       | padaone.geneids_to_taxids.geneIDs | 1      | Using index              |
|    3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | taxPath             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                              | PRIMARY                       | 4       | padaone.geneids_to_taxids.TaxID   | 1      | Using where              |
+------+--------------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+

-- ridiculously slow

SELECT
    pmid
FROM
    padaone_query_cache
WHERE
    (((first_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.0)
        AND (second_layer_probability BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0))
        AND (pmid IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT PMID AS pmid
        FROM
            geneIDs_PMIDs AS geneids_to_pmids
        INNER JOIN geneIDs_taxInfo_AccNumb AS geneids_to_taxids ON
            (geneids_to_pmids.geneIDs) = (geneids_to_taxids.geneIDs)
        WHERE
            EXISTS (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                taxPath
            WHERE
                taxPath.TaxID = geneids_to_taxids.TaxID
                AND FIND_IN_SET("7742", REPLACE(taxPath.LineagePath, "-", ",")) = 0))))
ORDER BY
    title DESC, -- the only difference
    pmid DESC
LIMIT 20;

-- EXPLAIN plan

+------+--------------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table               | type   | possible_keys                                                        | key                           | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra                                 |
+------+--------------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | padaone_query_cache | range  | PRIMARY,first_layer_probability_index,second_layer_probability_index | first_layer_probability_index | 5       | NULL                              | 221297 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | <subquery2>         | eq_ref | distinct_key                                                         | distinct_key                  | 4       | func                              | 1      |                                       |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED       | geneids_to_taxids   | index  | PRIMARY                                                              | taxIDsAccNumb_ibfk_1          | 5       | NULL                              | 338377 | Using where; Using index              |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED       | geneids_to_pmids    | ref    | PRIMARY,geneIDs_PMIDs_ibfk_2                                         | geneIDs_PMIDs_ibfk_2          | 4       | padaone.geneids_to_taxids.geneIDs | 1      | Using index                           |
|    3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | taxPath             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                              | PRIMARY                       | 4       | padaone.geneids_to_taxids.TaxID   | 1      | Using where                           |
+------+--------------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------+
```

What could be the issue here? Am I misusing indices? Is there a better way to deal with the original problem (queries taking >20s when ordering by any column other than `pmid`)? If there's any extra clarification needed I'll be happy to provide it. Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

In response to the comments, here is some extra information:

#### INDEX definitions and table

Here's the queries used to create the indices:

```sql
-- probability layers, work well for queries that are ordered by those columns
CREATE INDEX first_layer_probability_index ON padaone_query_cache (first_layer_probability, pmid, second_layer_probability);
CREATE INDEX second_layer_probability_index ON padaone_query_cache (second_layer_probability, pmid, first_layer_probability);

-- text columns such as `title`, doesn't do anything
CREATE INDEX title_index ON padaone_query_cache (title(35), pmid, first_layer_probability, second_layer_probability);

-- other numerical columns, speeds up those particular queries
CREATE INDEX year_pub_index ON padaone_query_cache (year_pub, pmid, first_layer_probability, second_layer_probability);
```

Here's the output of `SHOW INDEX`:

```sql
+---------------------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| Table               | Non_unique | Key_name                       | Seq_in_index | Column_name              | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+---------------------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| padaone_query_cache |          0 | PRIMARY                        |            1 | pmid                     | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | first_layer_probability_index  |            1 | first_layer_probability  | A         |        9032 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | first_layer_probability_index  |            2 | pmid                     | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | first_layer_probability_index  |            3 | second_layer_probability | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | second_layer_probability_index |            1 | second_layer_probability | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | second_layer_probability_index |            2 | pmid                     | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | second_layer_probability_index |            3 | first_layer_probability  | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | title_index                    |            1 | title                    | A         |      442595 |       35 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | title_index                    |            2 | pmid                     | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | title_index                    |            3 | first_layer_probability  | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | title_index                    |            4 | second_layer_probability | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | year_pub_index                 |            1 | year_pub                 | A         |          90 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | year_pub_index                 |            2 | pmid                     | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | year_pub_index                 |            3 | first_layer_probability  | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| padaone_query_cache |          1 | year_pub_index                 |            4 | second_layer_probability | A         |      442595 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+---------------------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
```

**NOTE**: This is boiled-down to a couple of index combinations that I tried and helped to picture the problem better. Do note that I ended up trying **lots** of different index combinations for the numeric and text columns - basically to no avail. Before writing this question I deleted all of them and started with a blank `INDEX` table, so I could build up from where I was before trying to add indices to speed up my queries.

#### Other relevant table schemas

Here's the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for `geneIDs_PMIDs` and `geneIDs_taxInfo_AccNumb`, both used in the `JOIN` query:

```sql
-- geneIDs_PMIDs
geneIDs_PMIDs | CREATE TABLE `geneIDs_PMIDs` (
  `PMID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `geneIDs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PMID`,
`geneIDs`),
  KEY `geneIDs_PMIDs_ibfk_2` (`geneIDs`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkMetadataPubPMIDgeneIDs` FOREIGN KEY (`PMID`) REFERENCES `metadataPub` (`PMID`) ON
DELETE
    CASCADE ON
    UPDATE
        CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT `geneIDs_PMIDs_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`geneIDs`) REFERENCES `geneIDs_taxInfo_AccNumb` (`geneIDs`) ON
        DELETE
            CASCADE ON
            UPDATE
                CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb3 COLLATE = utf8mb3_general_ci;

-- geneIDs_taxInfo_AccNumb
CREATE TABLE `geneIDs_taxInfo_AccNumb` (
  `geneIDs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `OrgTaxName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TaxID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccNumb` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`geneIDs`),
  KEY `taxIDsAccNumb_ibfk_1` (`TaxID`),
  CONSTRAINT `taxIDsAccNumb_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TaxID`) REFERENCES `taxPath` (`TaxID`) ON
DELETE
    CASCADE ON
    UPDATE
        CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb3 COLLATE = utf8mb3_general_ci;
```

#### Answers to some other suggestions

@tadman suggested hiring a DBA, but that's not a possibility. Maybe the lack of personal background didn't help, but I'm a PhD student in Genetics. I work in a Bioinformatics lab at a Brazilian public university. This database is not my work, it's a colleague's and I'm helping him make a web app out of it. I do have freedom to manipulate the database to some extent, but we're working with 0 budget and public data only. So hiring someone is out of the question.

@Rick James suggested to use `FULLTEXT` instead of `LIKE` for the text matching queries. I'm developing the backend in Rust, using [Diesel](https://diesel.rs/) as an ORM. I'm not sure Diesel has a DSL for fulltext queries. If it doesn't, I would have to resort to writing raw queries for this specific filter, which could break the current design of the backend. I'll take a closer look at it.

#### DB version

```bash
$ mysql --version
# mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.2-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

#### Number of rows in `padaone_query_cache`

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM padaone_query_cache;

-- output
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   525047 |
+----------+
```

If I missed anything else, feel free to comment it down below. And thanks for the suggestions so far.

Comment: This is why DBAs exist and why you might want to hire one to solve this specific problem.

Comment: Can you add to your question the Explain Plan of each of the queries in your question please? This will give you and us a pretty good Idea of what is happening on the database side. Just run each query with `explain` before it. Like `explain select.......`

Comment: Use `FULLTEXT` for such queries; `LIKE` with a leading wildcard and `OR` make those queries slow.

Comment: please show schemas using `show create table padaone_query_cache`, not desc; it is way way more helpful

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Edited the question and added the suggestions according to your comments. Thank you!